# has_many and belongs_to, how to print creator's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user table(id, username, ...), and I have a task table, this implies the tasks informations: task name, the creator's id and the task solver's id.

This is my dbase logic:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tasks,  :foreign_key=>"creator_id"
  has_many :tasks,  :foreign_key=>"solver_id"
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Is this right? In Task list I want to print the creators name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Task model you want:

```
 belongs_to :creator, :foreign_key => "creator_id", :class_name => "User"
 belongs_to :solver, :foreign_key => "solver_id", :class_name => "User"
```

and in your User model:

```
  has_many :created_tasks,  :foreign_key=>"creator_id", :class_name => "Task"
  has_many :solved_tasks,  :foreign_key=>"solver_id", :class_name => "Task"
```

So now you can do something like:

```
@user.created_tasks
@user.solved_tasks
```

and `@task.creator`
and `@task.solver`